# Setting a mock location programmatically in FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I am trying to use mock locations in my app for testing. To receive location updates I used the latest android developer documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates

This tutorial uses FusedLocationProviderClient and locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(createLocationRequest(), locationCallback, null) as example.

The issue is that I can no longer use permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

because I get the error "Permission is only granted to system apps" (I tried also in debug mode)

So I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
    locationClient.setMockMode(true);

    String[] tokens = location.split(",");
    Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    newLocation.setLatitude(Float.parseFloat(tokens[0]));
    newLocation.setLongitude(Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]));

    newLocation.setAccuracy(3.0f);

    newLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        newLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
    }
    locationClient.setMockLocation(newLocation);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that adding the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

permission to debug android manifest works even though Android Studio says "Permission is only granted to system apps".

So the solution is that, after adding it, run the application, then go to Settings / Developer options / Select mock location app -> here my app appears and I can select it.

I hope others can confirm and use this!

Comment: Didn't work for me - app appears in mock locations, but when setting a mock location app crashes with "com.app.package. from uid 10094 not allowed to perform MOCK_LOCATION"

Comment: Update (cannot delete downvote) - basically the device was showing the app's name as the mock location app and crashing when setting a mock location. However, when I manually set it to the mock location app (even though it was already showing as the mock location app!), it worked with no crash. So the answer above actually works. Would re-upvote if I could. Also, remember to set location mode to device only - otherwise the mock location will be overwritten by the real one.